# Форматирование формы ввода и правки вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Если попасть на страницу ввода вопроса через ссылку вида   [ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (например, при нажатии кнопки <kbd>Задать вопрос</kbd>), то форма выглядит приемлемо:

> [image: ask]

Но если после `ask` добавить слэш `/` ([ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/)), как это происходит, например, при переходе с [демо-страницы](http://demo.stackoverflow.ru/), то форматирование поля ввода заголовка съезжает:

> [image: ask-slash]

P.S. на демо-странице форматирование выглядит лучше всего:

> [image: demo-ask]

Путём просмотра исходного кода страниц видно разницу:

- приемлемое форматирование:

  `<body class="ask-page new-topbar">`
  `<a id="nav-askquestion"  style="cursor:default">Задать вопрос</a>`
- кривое:

  `<body class="question-page new-topbar">`
  `<a id="nav-askquestion"  href="/questions/ask">Задать вопрос</a>`

Видимо, дело в стилях.

Аналогичное нарушение размеров поля заголовка наблюдается при редактировании (ссылка <kbd>править</kbd> под телом) **любого** вопроса.

**Обновление**

Пример аналогичного поведения при правке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/690856/edit/

Comment: Просто чудеса какие–то!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это называется "баги"